# Use polynomial interpolation to find a formula

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Any idea how to Use polynomial interpolation to find $P_{k+1}$ where $P_{k+1}(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n j^k$ for $2\le k \le 10$? Thanks!

Comment: This may be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Got it! Thanks!